# How do we delete custom presets in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I've made some custom presets that I no longer need to use.  For example under the Colorize panel, you will see a list like this...

[image]

How can I remove some of these presets I no longer need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Manually:

- You find your [Gimp profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/)
- You open the `filters` directory in it
- You identify the file for your tool: likely `Gimp{toolname}Config.settings` for a tool, and `GimpGegl-gegl-{filter}-config.settings` for the GEGL filters.
- If you want to be brutal you just erase it
- If you don't want to erase all the presets you savedyou have to be a bit more careful. The file can be edited it a text editor:

  ```
  # settings

  (GimpLevelsConfig "2024-01-18 17:34:03"
      (time 1705595643)
      (linear no)
      (clamp-input no)
      (clamp-output no)
      (channel value)
      (low-input 0)
      (high-input 1)
      (gamma 1.0800000000000001)
      (low-output 0)
      (high-output 1)
      (channel red)
      (low-input 0.85487804878048779)
      (high-input 0.91829268292682931)
      (gamma 0.58999999999999997)
      (low-output 0.15853658536585366)
      (high-output 0.39756097560975612)
      (channel green)
      (low-input 0.68235294117647061)
      (high-input 0.76707317073170733)
      (gamma 0.85999999999999999)
      (low-output 0.10975609756097561)
      (high-output 0.26829268292682928)
      (channel blue)
      (low-input 0.27926829268292686)
      (high-input 0.60853658536585364)
      (gamma 0.92000000000000004)
      (low-output 0)
      (high-output 0.12073170731707317)
      (channel alpha)
      (low-input 0)
      (high-input 1)
      (gamma 1)
      (low-output 0)
      (high-output 1))
  (GimpLevelsConfig "LCH-Demo"
      (time 0)
      (linear no)
      (clamp-input no)
      (clamp-output no)
      (channel value)
      (low-input 0)
      (high-input 1)
      (gamma 1)
      (low-output 0)
      (high-output 1)
      (channel red)
      (low-input 0.85487804878048779)
      (high-input 0.91829268292682931)
      (gamma 0.58999999999999997)
      (low-output 0.15853658536585366)
      (high-output 0.39756097560975612)
      (channel green)
      (low-input 0.68235294117647061)
      (high-input 0.76707317073170733)
      (gamma 0.85999999999999999)
      (low-output 0.10975609756097561)
      (high-output 0.26829268292682928)
      (channel blue)
      (low-input 0.27926829268292686)
      (high-input 0.60853658536585364)
      (gamma 0.92000000000000004)
      (low-output 0)
      (high-output 0.12073170731707317)
      (channel alpha)
      (low-input 0)
      (high-input 1)
      (gamma 1)
      (low-output 0)
      (high-output 1))

  # end of settings
  ```

  where it is easy to identify settings that are automatically saved (their name is a time stamp and they have a `(time 1705595643)` (top one) and those explicitly saved (they have a name and `(time 0)` (bottom one).

#### Automatically (for the auto-saved ones):

The [`ofn-settings-cleaner` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) will run on every Gimp startup, and cleanup these files automatically using a configurable mix of age and count (settings that are explicitly saved aren't cleaned of course). The ZIP contains a HTML doc for installation/configuration. I have been running it for years (which is why I only have two entries in my Levels settings ).

Comment: I'm on Windows.  Can I simply add ofn-settings-cleaner.ini.sample-Gimp2.10, to the GIMP directory, and modify that file, to make this auto process work?

Comment: Yes, but rename it `ofn-settings-cleaner.ini` and it goes in the `filters` directory (while the `.py`goes in the `plug-ins` directory.

Comment: its kinda off-base, but why didn't the GIMP team allow the filters folder to be an option under Preferences, like the rest of the other folders we can see?

Comment: Not in the secrets of the gods, but the `Folders` thing in Preferences is more meant to add to the existing folders than to move them around, and there is only one `filters` folder (and also single `tool-options` and `tool-presets` folders).